# Get current unity3d version

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am writing a build utility function which generates asset bundles. I have implemented incremental building of assets. I want to ensure that when ever there is update in Unity3d version I want to ensure to build all the asset bundles again. Can anybody tell me how to get current version of Unity3d using script (C#/Javascript).
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems there are a few ways to do this.

First way is to use the [preprocessor definition's](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Script_compilation_28Advanced29.html) to check what version you have. I don't think this would be a solution to your problem, neverless, you use them like this:

```cs
// Specific version define including the minor revision
#if UNITY_2_6_0
// Use Unity 2.6.0 specific feature
#endif

// Specific version define not including the minor revision
#if UNITY_2_6
// Use Unity 2.6.x specific feature
#endif
```

More helpful to your situation would be to use the [GetFullUnityVersion](http://docs-jp.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/InternalEditorUtility.GetFullUnityVersion.html) function or the  [Application.unityVersion](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application-unityVersion.html) variable.

```cs
using UnityEditorInternal;
...
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
Debug.Log(
"Unity version = " + Application.unityVersion + "\n" +
"Full Unity version = " + InternalEditorUtility.GetFullUnityVersion() + "\n" +
"Version date = " + dt.AddSeconds(InternalEditorUtility.GetUnityVersionDate()));
```

You could store the current version in a file, and every time, check if the version is the same. If it isn't the same, you will have to rebuild the asset bundles.

Hope it helps!